# SQL error 26=-error locatig server. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to deploy my .NET webservice on to provider (somee.com). I published the webservice and copied the folder over to the hosting site. I have my App_data folder copied too. I can access the service webpage. But when trying to access the website I received the following error. I have sqlserver express on my local machine.

> A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

should i make i changes to my web.config file.

Please help

Comment: Does the web server have SQL Server installed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your ASP app to use the database provided by somee for you (see http://somee.com/MSSqlDefault.aspx), not the one in app_data. You also need to upload your deployment scripts and configure the somee provided database before you can start running your ASP app.